# PHP $_POST array always empty upon form submission

Tags: php, html

I'll start by saying that I've seen several similar questions asked but I've yet to find a solution to my problem.

I have the following on a page called `test.php`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php print_r($_POST); ?></p>
        <hr />
        <p><?php echo empty($_POST) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty'; ?></p>
        <hr />
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input id="example" type="text" />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After submitting the form with text in the input, the $_POST array is always empty.  Since several answers I've seen have mentioned PHP settings, I've copied my php.ini file below.

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 60
variables_order = "EGPCS"
extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
precision = 12
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

If it matters, I'm using GoDaddy hosting and haven't modified the default settings in any significant way.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to be using the name attribute, not the ID attribute. If no elements have a name attribute, no data will show up in the array.

```
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input name="example" type="text" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure how I missed that :)

Comment: I'm using "name" but have the same problem as the OP... any more suggestions?

Comment: OMG. I thought I was going nuts.  Its amazing the small details we can forget about simple HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the name attribute instead of or as well as id

```
<input name="example" id="example" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `name` attribute is used when sending data in a form submission. So you must have to specify the `name` attribute.

```
<input id="example" name="example" type="text" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except when I removed `encoding="text/plain"` from the `form`. That was apparently strictly not allowed.